# Restricting a column to accept only specific values

Tags: string, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, validation

I am trying to insert a formula in Excel 2010 so that the column lets the user enter a value only if it starts with `RM` or `TM` - if not, throw an error saying `"Needs to have either RM or TM in the starting of the value"`.

Is it possible to do this with just formulae?

Also, how do I apply this to an entire column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called Data Validation (DATA > Data Tools). Select your column (say `M`) and Data Validation..., Settings, Allow: Custom, Formula:

```
=OR(LEFT(M1,2)="RM",LEFT(M1,2)="TM")
```

Switch to Error Alert, Error message:

> Needs to have either RM or TM in the starting of the value.

OK. Other options to suit.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve it, please:

- select column or any other range
- check the address of active cell (on the left of formula bar - if you select full column it will be the first cell, and for the range it is the cell where you started selecting)
- add Custom validation with the following formula

  `=OR(LEFT(A1,2)="TM",LEFT(A1,2)="RM")`

(replace A1 with the address from the previous point)

- define your error message